# asp.net Master Page - want an image which carries on behind main page

Tags: asp.net, image, master-pages

Well this is a bit of a head-scratcher (at least for me).

Basically, I've got a Master Page set up, which has the usual buttons and our logo.

I've been provided with a header image which our company wants setting on the Master Page, but it's too big and I want it to overflow down onto (and behind) the main page(s), without terminating suddenly and looking silly. I've messed around a little with the z-index (setting it as a regular img) but to no avail.

Could anyone point me in the right direction as to how I should go about this?

Code:

```
<%@ Master Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="Site.master.cs" Inherits="SiteMaster" %>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en">
<head runat="server">
<title></title>
<link href="~/Styles/Site.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="HeadContent" runat="server">

</asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
<style type="text/css">
    .style1
    {
        color: #CC3300;
        background-color: #FFFFFF;
    }
    .auto-style2 {
        font-size: small;
        display: block;
        text-align: left;
        padding: 10px;
        color: White;
        background-color: #FFFFFF;
    }
    </style>

<script type="text/javascript" src="//ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jQuery/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="//ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.ui/1.10.2/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/../ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.ui/1.10.2/themes/ui-lightness/jquery-ui.css" type="text/css" />

<script type="text/javascript">
var timoutNow = 900000; // Timeout in 15 Mins.
var logoutUrl = 'Default.aspx'; // URL to logout page.
var timeoutTimer;

// Start timers.
function StartTimers()
{
    timeoutTimer = setTimeout("IdleTimeout()", timoutNow);
}

// Reset timers.
function ResetTimers()
{
    clearTimeout(timeoutTimer);
    StartTimers();
}

// Logout the user.
function IdleTimeout()
{
    window.location = logoutUrl;
}
</script>

</head>
<body onload="StartTimers();" onmousemove="ResetTimers();">
<form runat="server">
<div class="page">
    <div class="header">
        <div class="auto-style2">
            <img alt="" class="style1" src="CompanyLogo.jpg" style="background-position: right top; white-space: nowrap; position: absolute; width: 166px; height: 80px; top: 2px; right: 8px;" />
            <asp:HyperLink ID="HyperLink1" runat="server" ForeColor="Black" NavigateUrl="~/Default.aspx">Log off</asp:HyperLink>
        </div>
        <div class="clear hideSkiplink">
            <asp:Menu ID="NavigationMenu" runat="server" CssClass="menu" EnableViewState="false" IncludeStyleBlock="false" Orientation="Horizontal">
                <Items>
                    <asp:MenuItem NavigateUrl="~/ReportMenu.aspx" Text="Reports" 
                        Value="Dashboard"/>
                    <asp:MenuItem NavigateUrl="~/SiteMan.aspx" Text="Site Manager" Value="Dev Menu">
                    </asp:MenuItem>
                    <asp:MenuItem Text="Team Manager" Value="Team Manager" 
                        NavigateUrl="~/TeamMan.aspx"></asp:MenuItem>
                    <asp:MenuItem NavigateUrl="~/Ticksheets.aspx" Text="Ticksheets" 
                        Value="Ticksheets"></asp:MenuItem>
                    <asp:MenuItem NavigateUrl="~/Scheduler.aspx" Text="Scheduler" Value="Scheduler">
                    </asp:MenuItem>
                    <asp:MenuItem NavigateUrl="~/Updater.aspx" Text="Updater" Value="Updater">
                    </asp:MenuItem>
                    <asp:MenuItem Text="Monitoring" Value="Monitoring" 
                        NavigateUrl="~/Monitoring.aspx"></asp:MenuItem>
                </Items>
            </asp:Menu>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="main">
        <asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="MainContent" runat="server"/>
    </div>
    <div class="clear">
    </div>
</div>
<div class="footer">

</div>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve that using the css background property.

```
body { 
  background: url("topbanner.png") #00D repeat-y fixed; 
}
```

Refer: [background](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/background)

Comment: Seems good, I'm just having trouble finding where to place this in the code. I'm going back to using a regular img as that does what I need, except for staying behind things using a z-index of -1 without it disappearing. Confusing (at least to my feeble brain - too early in the morning).

Comment: Put this in your style tags. You can center it to the screen using CSS too.

Comment: Sorry, still having trouble placing it (or getting the syntax correct). I can put the (background: url("topbanner.png") #00D repeat-y fixed;) bit in my styles, but that doesn't look right (puts it into all the separate bits on the page, starting new). I've put in a separate .body style but it doesn't know to call that.

Comment: Working a bit better now (I didn't realise it would recognise it as body rather than .body) - again, still having trouble placing it. I want it as the background on the page, not behind the page itself. Getting there though...

Comment: Marked as answer as I'm now using the suggested code. When I'd gotten the image onto the page as I thought I wanted it (even though I was still messing around with getting it how I wanted it) the image clashed too much with the text. So now I'm putting it behind the actual page itself.